# For loop not giving proper result

Tags: javascript

```
var integer = 10;
var plus = [];

for(var i = 2; i < integer; i++) {
     if(integer % i === 0){
       plus.push[i];
     }  
   }
console.log(plus)
```

this prints empty array, but why? shoudnt it print [2, 5]? I cant find what is wrong in my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this works :

```js
var integer = 10;
var plus = [];
for (var i = 2; i < integer; i++) {
    if (integer % i === 0) {
        plus.push(i);
    }
}
console.log(plus)
```

so, basically what you were doing wrong is using `.push[i]`. its a common syntax error. you just need to use [.push(i)](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp)

Answer (score 1):

`plus.push(i);` instead of using `plus.push[i];`

Answer (score 0):

Functions are objects in JavaScript. `plus.push[i];` looks up a property on `push`, the function object, using `i`'s value as the name (exactly like indexing into an array); and then throws away whatever value it got (presumably `undefined`, as the function probably doesn't have properties named `"2"`, `"4"`, etc.). That's why you're not getting a syntax error, as you would in many other languages.

To **call** `push`, use `()`, not `[]`:

```
plus.push(i);
```